# XML SelectNode() returns nothing. Why does namespace matter?

Tags: c#, xml

I have code to get the nodes of a root element:

```
xmlNodes = rootElement.SelectNodes("DefinitionName");
```

It's not returning nodes that exist. In the debugger, I can expand rootElement to find DefinitionName. Apparently the problem is the fact that the file has a namespace defined (see XML below). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4bektfx9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that I have to do something like this to get nodes to return:

Note: This has nothing to do with my code. This is the example from MSDN:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.lucernepublishing.com");
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//ab:book", nsmgr);
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does the namespace matter? If I want a node, and it exists, just give it to me.
2. My app processes many XML files. How am I supposed to specify the namespace (`nsmgr.AddNamespace()`)? Do I need to parse the file to get that first?

I can't help but feeling that I'm taking the long, angst-filled way of doing this.

This is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SessionStateInfo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    z:Id="1" z:Type="Company.Apps.MoreHere.Session.SessionStateInfo"
    z:Assembly="assembly info here"
    xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MoreHere.Session">
      <CoaterNumber>25</CoaterNumber>
      <DefinitionName z:Id="2">Two Line</DefinitionName>
      <EnableManualMode>true</EnableManualMode>
```

Comment: A node is identified not just by its local name (in your example, DefinitionName), but by the combination of its namespace URI and its local name. Note that the prefix per se doesn't matter apart from defining the namespace URI. So a:x and b:x and just x are, in general, different nodes: x is in the global NS, while a:x and b:x are likely in different NSs. Exceptions are: prefixes a and b could refer to the same NS URI, or x can be in a NS after all due to a default NS being in effect. However, from your post, I don't see why DefinitionName would be in the www.lucernepublishing.com NS.

Comment: @Dabbler My bad about www.lucernepublishing.com. I added a note to show that was just the MSDN example, and has nothing to do with my code. Can there be two nodes, with the same name, in the same file, with different namespaces for each?

Comment: You can do this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:books="http://www.bobhorns-books.com" xmlns:paintings="http://www.bobhorns-paintings.com">
   <books:title/>
   <paintings:title/>
</root>
The elements' local names are the same (which is probably what you are referring to by "name"), but remember a node is always defined by the combination of its namespace URI and its local name, which is the entire point of namespaces. This example shows one can work with book titles and painting titles without introducing ambiguities.

Comment: None of your elements are actually in a namespace so it should work as it is without needing a namespace manager (assuming `rootElement` is the `SessionStateInfo` element).  Does your real XML have a declaration for that `z:` prefix?  As it stands your example is not namespace-well-formed, which may be confusing matters.

Comment: So the fact that the element/node isn't prefixed with a namespace doesn't matter. One must get nodes by namespace if a namespace is defined in the file?

Comment: You can use the xpath function 'local-name()' like //*[local-name()='book'] this will match all book nodes even if they have different namespaces.
I totally agree to Dabbler, if you assume you know the node node then you should also assume that you know the namespace.

Comment: My original post had items removed from the XML that I thought wouldn't be important to the discussion. I just updated my post with the full, top portion, of the XML doc.

Comment: *If* the node resides in a NS, then it must be accessed via that NS, yes. (To say "if a NS is defined in the file" is a little to simplistic, because NS definitions can reside anywhere in the document tree, affecting some nodes but not others.) However, I don't see that DefinitionName actually is in a NS.

Comment: Ah, so the real XML _does_ have a default namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`), that changes things considerably...

Comment: Yes, that changes everything :-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<SessionStateInfo ....
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MoreHere.Session">
```

means that this element and all its descendants are in the `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MoreHere.Session` namespace.  Since unprefixed names in an XPath always refer to elements in *no* namespace, you will need to bind this URI to a prefix and use that prefix in your XPath, even though no prefix is in use in the document.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("mhs", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MoreHere.Session");
xmlNodes = rootElement.SelectNodes("mhs:DefinitionName", nsmgr);
```

If you know that the element(s) you are looking for will always have the same local name but may or may not have a namespace (or may have different namespaces) then you can use XPath tricks like

```
rootElement.SelectNodes("*[local-name() = 'DefinitionName']");
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. This answers my first question. But I can't hard-code the namespace in my code, because I don't know it ahead of time. Some XML docs will have a namespace, and some won't. Can you answer my second point/question in my question?

Comment: @BobHorn I've added a hack you can use if necessary, but namespaces are usually there for a reason - the point of using them is that the element named `DefinitionName` in namespace A shouldn't be treated the same as the element named `DefinitionName` in namespace B...

Comment: It's surprising you would have nodes reside in NSs and later, when processing them, claim you know about the nodes but not the NSs. Because if all you care about are their local names, despite the nodes living in disjoint worlds (so to speak), this makes the use of NSs seem superfluous. But if this really is what you want, you can ignore the NS by calling local-name() as suggested by Siraf.

Comment: This is for a deployment app. The user specifies a node to change during the deployment process. The app itself doesn't know anything about any of the files it will process; it's just there to change nodes based on user input. So perhaps the missing piece is that I need to have the user specify an option namespace as well?

Comment: That's quite possible. From a pure XML (+ namespaces) point of view, nodes residing in different namespaces are completely unrelated, regardless of whether their local names happen to be equal or not. Whether you would want to apply the same processing to them based on just their local name goes beyond the XML scope of things and can only be answered on a business logic level.

Answer (score 2):

It matters because if there's a namespace attached, then "DefinitionName" is not enough. Imagine you have been given a list of people, all with the first name John:

- John Smith
- John Jones
- John Murphy

What you're doing is the equivalent of asking for "John," instead of "John Smith" for example.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the answer to the question but it may be an alternative solution using `XDocument`

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load("SessionStateInfo.xml");
            XNamespace nameSpace = document.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement node = document.Descendants(nameSpace + "DefinitionName").FirstOrDefault();   

            if (node != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cool! XDocument rocks! value: {0}", node.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Spoot! Didn't find it!");
            }
        }      
    }       
}
```

This seems to work if the default namespace is specified or not.